# Thymeleaf - How to add url to relative url

Tags: thymeleaf

I have a form page into:

```
GET /admin/form
```

Instead of send to full relative path like:

```
th:action="@{/admin/form}"
```

i would like to send to:

```
th:action="@{**** I dont know how to set '/admin' from thymeleaf **** /form}"
```

In other words i want to get the path (/admin) programmatically. How can i do it and add '/form'?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get param from controller dynamically, just set a method like this:

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "form", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String messages(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("param", "admin");
        return "form/";
    }
```

And then in html you can get it like this:

```
  <form th:action="@{/${param}/form}">
```

You can include parameters statically in the form of path variables like this :

```
<form th:action="@{/{param}/form(param='admin')}">
```

So if we formulize the path :

```
<form th:action="@{/staticpath/{dynamicpath}(dynamicpath=${type})}">
```

Comment: I guess it is the same as i write `th:action="@{/admin/form}"` and im not getting the `\admn` programatically

Comment: Which technology do you use at background? Something like Spring mvc?

Comment: Yes, i use spring.

Comment: Send "admin" as a patrameter in model? Is this work for you?